# Url Request req.wait() causing issue in apk

Tags: python, kivy

My src code is working fine when tested from kivy launcher but when build an apk and debugged with buildozer logcat seems that req.wait() is causing issue and is in hung state infinitely.Print after wait is never printed in log.

Any known issue or suggestions to fix this?

```
req = UrlRequest( url = LOGIN_URL , method = 'GET' ,on_success = self.success, debug = True )
req.wait()
print "After login"
print req
```

Comment: Can you pastebin the whole log? And do you have the INTERNET permission?

Comment: how to add internet permissions ?

Comment: In the buildozer.spec

Comment: my bad got it ..... will try  once more

Comment: thanks its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of marking the question as answered: you needed the INTERNET permission.